# Oven does not have a temperature notification sound

Tags: oven, temperature

Oven is in new condition, however about 10 yeqrs old. The oven does not have a signal to let you know when desired temperature has been reached. Mfg. suggested using an oven thermometer probe.  A probe attached to a wire that goes inside oven connected to a wire and to a battery operated control unit outside of oven.  My question, is than an alternative to this method?  Thank you

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What are you looking for in an alternative?

Comment: Do I understand you right that your oven has a thermostat controlling the temperature, and you would like to know when the specified temp. has been reached? ... There must be a way to tell whether the heat source of the oven (whether gas burner or glowing electric element) is on or off, so when you first turn the oven on, the heat source will go on, and after a few (or ten or so) minutes, when the selected temperature is reached, the heat source should shut off for a while. That would be the indicator. ... or is your question something else?

Comment: I've never had an oven that made a special sound when it reached temperature. Just listen for the gas to stop flowing (or the light to go out on an electric oven).

Comment: Danial, thank you for your quick response. On every other gas range I’ve operated, a buzzer or beeper would sound off when desired temp. Is reached.  This range does not make any sort of sound.    I don’t hear any sound indicating the gas stopped flowing, so far the only way I know the temp has been reached is by using the in-oven probe thermometer, which is not convienent.

Comment: Do you want/need acoustic notification explicitly?

Comment: What is *Mfg.*?

Comment: Asking because there are oven thermometers that just plain old go in the oven whole - you can leave them in normally.

Answer (score 1):

Oven temperatures vary depending on insulation and, the big, how often you open the door. I would recommend using the described 'remote' thermometer or an oven thermometer positioned where it can be read through the glass in the door (assuming that would be possible). Set you oven to it's highest setting and time how long it takes to reach that temperature. Once you know how long it takes to reach 'max' use a timer that will give you the audible cue you are seeking at that length of time, regardless of what temperature you may be using at that time. If you want your oven a 325°F and it takes 10 minutes to get to 500°F...it will 'safely' be at 325°F in 10 minutes, once you test it, trust it. Baking rarely requires such an exact temperature control that the variance created would be problematic.

Extending the pre-heat time for your oven is not a bad thing, indeed it helps with the recovery time that it takes to return to the set temp after being opened and closed.